# image corrupted by FileUpload

Tags: java, http, post, webserver, netty

I need to make a HTTP server for recieving and sending images and text(less than 100 characters) to the client. I am planning to use JSON or Google Protocol Buffer.

I studied the "HttpUploadServer" example in the Netty 4.0.6 package.

Then, I deleted everything in the handler except things dealing with multipart POST requests.

Here's the part where I am struggling with.

```
private void writeHttpData(InterfaceHttpData data) {
    FileUpload fileUpload = (FileUpload)data;
    try {
        File file = fileUpload.getFile();
        file.renameTo(new File("C:\\savedFiles\\"+file.getName()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I call getFile(), it gives me a corrupted file. I've tested it with zip files, and images(png, jpeg). 
(BTW. I am using Postman add-on to test the server, so wrong headers are not my problem)

Is there a way to make this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on Github

Change

```
private static final HttpDataFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataFactory(DefaultHttpDataFactory.MINSIZE);
```

to

```
private static final HttpDataFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataFactory(false);
```

or

```
private static final HttpDataFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataFactory(true);
```

for me setting it true worked!